# Does "definition" of probability in terms of densities imply probability for non-Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}?$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

To my understanding, rigorously speaking, probability for real-valued random variables or random vectors ($n$-tuples of real numbers) is defined only for $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ (the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$), i.e. probability (for random vectors) is, by definition, strictly a function $\mathsf{P} : \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \rightarrow [0, 1]$

However in more "elementary" (non-measure-theoretic) texts, one may encounter definitions like this:

> The random variables $X$ and $Y$ are said to be ***jointly continuous*** if there exists a function $f$ of two real arguments having for each subset C of the plane the property that $P \{ (X, Y) \in C \} = \iint_{C} f(x, y) dx dy$

On its face, this sort of implies an assignment of probability to ***non-Borel*** but ***measurable*** subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, but I suspect that this is not the intent (rather, that the author is just trying to avoid talking about "Borel sets" to an audience who might not know what that means).

Is it correct to assume that an "elementary" definition like the one quoted above should be interpreted as pertaining only to ***Borel*** subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Comment: That definitiion is fine for Lebesuge measurable sets $C$.  But note that not all random variables have densities.  And then items like $P \{ (X, Y) \in C \}$ may fail to exist for a Lebesgue measurable but non-Borel set $C$.